# PHP- Moving file using URL

Tags: php

So the scenario is, I have an ecommerce site which involves users uploading files & details, the links to the files & the text of the details is saved into a text file. All this stuff is uploaded into a temporary folder.

The payment system I have integrated is Paypal. I have Paypal send a response to the IPN. In this file, I send some emails, but I also wish to move the files into a permanent folder and thus edit the links in the text file. But I can't seem to access the files properly.

This is my error codes:

```
file_get_contents( ../uploads/tmp/file/*FILE NAME HERE*.doc) [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/*username here*/public_html/*name*/*dir*/ipn.php on line 103

PHP Warning:  file_put_contents( ../uploads/tmp/file/*FILE NAME HERE*.doc) [<a href='function.file-put-contents'>function.file-put-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/*username here*/public_html/*name*/*dir*/ipn.php on line 103

PHP Warning:  copy( ../uploads/tmp/file/*FILE NAME HERE*).doc) [<a href='function.copy'>function.copy</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in *link to ipn.php* on line 106
```

//This is my code

```
if ($key ==  'Book File '){
    $oldBookFileName = $result['Book File '];
    $oldBookLink = str_replace('*BASE URL IS HERE*',     '../',$oldBookFileName);
    if (strpos($result['Book File '],'/tmp/') !== false) {
        $newBookFileName = str_replace("/tmp/","/perm   /",$oldBookFileName);
        $newBookLink = str_replace('*BASE URL IS HERE*', '../',$newBookFileName);
    }
    //update file names in file & move files
   //include ('updatefile.php');
   file_put_contents($oldBookLink, str_replace($oldBookFileName,     $newBookFileName, file_get_contents($oldBookLink)));
    //copy/move files from tmp to perm
    copy($oldBookLink, $newBookLink);
    }
```

I've tried using the full path (www.example.com/dir/file.php)  and using the relative path (../dir/file.php). Also, all the links are correct, I echo'ed them out in an email and they are correct.

Anyone know what Im doing wrong? Something totally retarded? Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a need to mention you have paypal and are those extra spaces necessary?

Comment: You need to make sure that you have permission for the Sever to Read and Execute  `file_put_contents()` without letting the Client modify anything.

Comment: EdSF -  stackoverflow suggested paypal as a tag, not me. Class - well yes because I don't know what the problem is, therefore I don't know if the problem has anything to do with paypal. & yes the spaces are necessary at this moment in time. thanks for the 'help'....PHPglue - I managed to edit the text file, but no luck in moving the files, it works if I put the hardcode the urls into the 'copy' myself but not when i use variables that contain the same string...? Gah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have the relative path wrong. Try using realpath() to see what path PHP is actually using.

For the full path you need to use the path on the server, not the http URL. So something like `/home/username/public_html/dir/filename.doc` instead of `www.example.com/dir/filename.doc`

Comment: It was because there were spaces in the doc file name, so I now I remove the spaces before uploading the file. Thanks for your help. =)